# How to generate a string based on another given string's length?

Tags: erlang

I am trying to generate a string based on length of another given string.
My code is :

```
generate(S1,S2)->
LenString1 = length(S1),
LenString2 = length(S2),
L = LenString1 div LenString2,
lists:flatten(lists:duplicate(L,S2)).
```

but is this case it does not work :

```
generate("Some", "Key")
```

or

```
generate("Generate","Key")
```

the result I need is :

```
KeyK
```

or

```
KeyKeyKe
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why so complicated?

```
generate(S1, S2) ->
    generate(S2, S1, S2).

generate(S2, [_|_] = S1, []) ->
    generate(S2, S1, S2);
generate(S2, [_|S1], [H|T]) ->
    [H | generate(S2, S1, T)];
generate(S2, [], _) when is_list(S2) -> [];
generate(_, _, _) -> error(badarg).
```

Answer (score 3):

You also need to take the first `LenString1 rem LenString2` characters and append that to the result of `flatten`:

```
generate(S1, S2)->
  LenString1 = length(S1),
  LenString2 = length(S2),
  L = LenString1 div LenString2,
  Extra = LenString1 rem LenString2,
  lists:flatten(lists:duplicate(L, S2)) ++ lists:sublist(S2, Extra).
```

```
1> a:generate("Some", "Key").
"KeyK"
2> a:generate("Generate", "Key").
"KeyKeyKe"
```